# Upload File on SharePoint Online through a Javascript app hosted externally

Tags: provider-hosted-app, app

I am working on a SharePoint Site , and I have got a new requirement from a user (Office 365 User), to provide them a way of directly uploading a file from the web app instead of going to the SharePoint.

Additionally, the web app team managing the app wants to have the page hosted in the app, instead of SharePoint.

I saw lot of examples online on uploading files to the SharePoint site, but it isn't very clear if I have to host the page within the SharePoint itself.

Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by leveraging the REST API. There is a good example on MSDN located here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx

Comment: It is clearly written in the page you recommended.."The context for this example is a SharePoint-hosted add-in that uploads a file to a folder on the host web." My requirement is to host it independently.